# How to remove header underline from certain columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

I want to remove the header text underline but only for some columns not all of them.

How can I do it?

Comment: The underlines come because you've provided the SortExpression, do you want to sort these columns?

Comment: Yes I wanna sort them but only from 1 column wich is Date

Comment: I have 10 columns and one of them is called Date ( format datetime) . I want to remove the underline from all columns but not from the Date one , so I can sort the rows of the gridview by the clicking the header of the Date column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `autogeneratecolumns="false"` and `allowsorting="true"`. Then you will need to define all of the columns you want to display in a `<columns>` child element to the gridview like so:

```
<columns>
     <asp:boundfield datafield="Date" headertext="Date" sortexpression="Date"/>
     <asp:boundfield datafield="OtherColumn" headertext="Other Data"/>
</columns>
```

When you use `autogeneratecolumns="true"` and `allowsorting="true"` by default all columns will be sortable. When you explicitly define the columns, those that do not have the `sortexpression` property set will not be sortable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RowDataBound` to remove the underline of the  `LinkButton`.

This removes the underline from all columns but the one with `HeaderText == "Date":`

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Row.RowType)
    {
        case DataControlRowType.Header:
            var notDateFields = ((GridView)sender).Columns
                 .Cast<DataControlField>()
                 .Select((c, index) => new { Column = c, Index = index })
                 .Where(x => x.Column.HeaderText != "Date");
            foreach (var field in notDateFields)
            {
                LinkButton Link = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[field.Index].Controls[0];
                Link.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration:none;");
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

This approach only sets the style so that the underline is removed but allows to sort the column anyway.

If you just want to prevent that the column is sortable, you only have to remove the `SortExpression` property.